# Alternative to tcm.exe testcase /import under Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Under Visual Studio 2017, I was using `tcm.exe testcase /import` against my test DLL and my on-prem Azure Dev Ops server. This would create my test case and associate each test against the test case. But Visual Studio 2019 is missing the tcm.exe. Is there an alternative to tcm.exe for I to create test case and assign them to my test automatically because having to do this manually under Test Explorer is a tedious task?

The tcm.exe is missing under the Visual Studio 2019 "Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE" folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this tool too and noticed it was missing in VS 2019.  I submitted a similar question on the Visual Studio forums and this is the answer I got.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67437b63-f94f-43f9-a7cd-abcd2d3e3b4d/tcmexe-utility-missing-from-visual-studio-2019?forum=vsunittest

Looks like there was an oversight in bringing this tool forward on the new VS 2019.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I've voted on your "suggested feature" on Dev Community. Hopefully this gets added in an update soon.